# Can Hi-rib cementing be used to level a second story floor?

Tags: self-leveling-concrete

Is it advisable to use the hi rib cementing style to correct the whole un level wooden second floor area? It is not level from between 1 to 2 and 3/4 inches in certain areas.

Answer (score 4):

No.  Hy-Rib is an exterior industrial product not intended for residential use, and IIRC you'd never cover it completely w/ less than 2 full inches of concrete, adding an incredible amount of weight to your WOODEN structure.

If your floor is that far out of level, that suggests problems in the underlying framing.  The best fix is to correct from the bottom up - start in the basement and adjust the 1st floor to level or as near level as possible, then repeat working your way up the house.

Comment: What about self-leveling compound, which I assume is a kind of plastic resin and therefore much lighter? (I'm guessing on that, so please let me know as I'm considering something like Mapei Self Leveling Compound.)

Comment: @Volomike you should probably ask a new question, instead of trying to ask questions via comments on answers.

Comment: That said, the only self-leveling compounds I've seen were concrete.